# I have a response API as HTML below. I want to get 355310 for set an environment variable in postman

Tags: html, postman

I post a picture with the response that the API returns like below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/irL6Z.jpg

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like you want to parse some JSON data using the javascript "Test" tab of postman to read a specific array value of the data-extend attribute.  The only problem I see is that the article tags are not unique on that page aside from what is in the data-extend attribute.  So I think at best you'll be iterating through each  on the page and pulling the ID out.  like this:

```js
let articles = document.body.getElementsByTagName('article');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(articles, e => {
    if ( e.hasAttribute('data-extend') ) {
        var article = JSON.parse( e.getAttribute('data-extend') );
        console.log( article['vid'] );
    }
});
```

[image]